# Angular 2 - GUI not update when change model in Promise

Tags: angular, service, components

I write a service return a promise, and in the component i call service and set model to data return from success function of promise the model is changed but GUI is not update. How can I solve this issues .

```ts
Service : 

getPage(pageNo) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) {
    this.http.get(this.dataGetPageUrl+"/" + pageNo)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(
        blocks => {
          resolve(blocks);
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  })
}


Component: 

Service.getPage(1).then(function(data) {
  this.model = data;
}).catch(function(error) {

})
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of `function` `this.` doesn't point to the current class. Use `()=>` (arrow function) instead:

```ts
Service.getPage(1).then((data) => {
  this.model = data;
}).catch((error) => {
```

Comment: I already use your code, it show correct length result of data but doesn't render the list data with ngFor.

Comment: Any error in the console? How does the code for `*ngFor` look like?

Comment: It has no error, it show the length of array is 10, and it render 10 row, but the data in each cell is empty, but data in model is not empty. Here is the code ngFor. Sorry i don't know how to format :

Comment: You can't format code in comments. You can wrap in single backticks ` to ensure it is rendered as code. It's better to edit the question and add code there.

Comment: Hard to tell why it's not rendered. I think that would require a Plunker to reproduce.

Comment: Sorry, It is my mistake, It work now, thank you so much for your help